# Angular JS some result doesn't show in Google Chrome but show in FireFox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, ionic-framework

I have created a SelectedProduct factory to save data from ProductDetailCtrl and retrieve the data in ProductOrder Ctrl

**The factory is as below**

```
    .factory('SelectedProduct',function(){
var products = {};

return{
    addCategory: function(_category){
        return products.category = {category: _category};
    },
    addSelectedProduct: function(_name,_image,_quantity,_price){
        return products.item = {name: _name, image: _image,quantity: _quantity,price: _price};
    },
    getSelectedProduct: function(){
        return products.item;
    },
    getCategory:function(){
        return products.category
    }
}
})
```

**In my product_detail.html, I save the parameter by ng-click in :**

```
 <img ng-src="{{product.image}}" alt="{{product.product_name}}"  ng-click="SelectImage((detail.image = product.image),(detail.name = product.product_name),(detail.quantity = product.quantity),(detail.price = product.price))" width="500" height="340">
```

**In ProductDetailCtrl:**

```
SelectedProduct.addCategory($stateParams.categoryName);
$scope.SelectImage = function () {
    SelectedProduct.addSelectedProduct($scope.detail.name,$scope.detail.image,$scope.detail.quantity,$scope.detail.price);
};
```

**Then I call the saved data in product_order.html:**

```
<h3>RM {{selectedProduct.price}}</h3>
```

**My ProductOrderCtrl:**

```
$scope.selectedProduct = SelectedProduct.getSelectedProduct();
var categoryName = SelectedProduct.getCategory();
```

BUT the output only can't show in chrome browser, it works fine in my device, and other browsers. I just wondering why would it be like this. Any idea and reason about this problem?

**Note:**
Other data like name, image link works fine in chrome but just the price in 00.00 format can't show. the price retrieved from MySQL online and is stored in varchar.

**Result from Chrome**

[image: This is the output from Google Chrome]

[image: This is the output from FireFox]

**Result from FireFox**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some caching in Google Chrome, try **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** option which can be performed in developer mode, by a simple right click on refresh button!